# Ant moves on n circles

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

There are n circles on the plane such that each of the circles crosses each other at two points, and no three circles share a point. We put one ant on one of the circles. It starts to move clockwise. When the ant reaches a cross point, it continues to move on another circle in the anti-clockwise direction, again it changes the direction to clockwise when it reaches another cross point. Show that n should be odd such that the ant can traverse all the circles exactly once and reaches the start point.

Comment: @CalvinLin: $n=2$ does not work, but $n=3$ does.

Comment: Ah thanks, I think I understand the setup now.